# Error while trying to transfer SPL tokens using @solana/spl-token

Tags: web3.js, spl-token

I'm getting this error while trying to transfer SPL tokens. I've seen people getting similar errors while trying to transfer SPL tokens but I can't figure out how to fix this:

```
if (!allowOwnerOffCurve && !web3_js_1.PublicKey.isOnCurve(owner.toBuffer()))
                                                                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toBuffer')
```

This is my JS script:

```
const { Connection, Keypair, PublicKey } = require('@solana/web3.js');
const { getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount, transfer } = require('@solana/spl-token');

const mint = new PublicKey(process.argv[2]);
const toWallet = new PublicKey(process.argv[3]);
const amount= (process.argv[4]);

async function transferSPLToken() {
    // Connect to cluster
    const connection = new Connection('MY-CUSTOM-RPC-URL');

    // Generate a new wallet keypair and airdrop SOL
    const fromWalletKeypair = [...];
    const fromWallet = Keypair.fromSecretKey(Buffer.from(fromWalletKeypair, 'hex'))

    // Get the token account of the fromWallet address, and if it does not exist, create it
    const fromTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
        connection,
        fromWallet,
        mint,
        fromWallet.publicKey
    );

    // Get the token account of the toWallet address, and if it does not exist, create it
    const toTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(connection, fromWallet, mint, toWallet.publicKey);

    // Transfer the new token to the "toTokenAccount" we just created
    signature = await transfer(
        connection,
        fromWallet,
        fromTokenAccount.address,
        toTokenAccount.address,
        fromWallet.publicKey,
        amount
    );
    console.log('transfer tx:', signature);
}

transferSPLToken()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `toWallet` is set here as a PublicKey:

```
const toWallet = new PublicKey(process.argv[3]);
```

And the issue may due to using `toWallet.publicKey` here:

```
const toTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(connection, fromWallet, mint, toWallet.publicKey);
```

Try just `toWallet` since you have it already set as a PublicKey